# Why is my ListView not populating with data? No errors and I can see the data in the console in VS, .NET Maui application using JSON from API

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, maui

Here is my Model class - Posts.cs in Models folder:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace App.Models
{
    // Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse);
    public class CommunityBannerImage
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("mimetype")] public string Mimetype { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("width")] public int Width { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("height")] public int Height { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("size")] public int Size { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("averageColor")] public string AverageColor { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("url")] public string Url { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("copies")] public List<Copy> Copies { get; set; }
    }

    public class CommunityProPic
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("mimetype")] public string Mimetype { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("width")] public int Width { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("height")] public int Height { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("size")] public int Size { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("averageColor")] public string AverageColor { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("averageColor")] public string Url { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("copies")] public List<Copy> Copies { get; set; }
    }

    public class Copy
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("copyId")] public string CopyId { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("width")] public int Width { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("height")] public int Height { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("size")] public int Size { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("url")] public string Url { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("objectFit")] public string ObjectFit { get; set; }
    }

    public class Image
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("mimetype")] public string Mimetype { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("width")] public int Width { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("height")] public int Height { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("size")] public int Size { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("averageColor")] public string AverageColor { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("url")] public string Url { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("copies")] public List<Copy> Copies { get; set; }
    }

    public class Link
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("url")] public string Url { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("hostname")] public string Hostname { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("image")] public Image Image { get; set; }
    }

    public class Post
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("id")] public string Id { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("type")] public string Type { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("publicId")] public string PublicId { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("userId")] public string UserId { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("username")] public string Username { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("userGroup")] public string UserGroup { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("userDeleted")] public bool UserDeleted { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("isPinned")] public bool IsPinned { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("communityId")] public string CommunityId { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("communityName")] public string CommunityName { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("communityProPic")] public CommunityProPic CommunityProPic { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("communityBannerImage")] public CommunityBannerImage CommunityBannerImage { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("title")] public string Title { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("body")] public object Body { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("link")] public Link Link { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("locked")] public bool Locked { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("lockedBy")] public object LockedBy { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("lockedAt")] public object LockedAt { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("upvotes")] public int Upvotes { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("downvotes")] public int Downvotes { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("hotness")] public object Hotness { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("createdAt")] public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("editedAt")] public object EditedAt { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("lastActivityAt")] public DateTime LastActivityAt { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("deleted")] public bool Deleted { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("deletedAt")] public object DeletedAt { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("deletedContent")] public bool DeletedContent { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("noComments")] public int NoComments { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("comments")] public object Comments { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("commentsNext")] public object CommentsNext { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("userVoted")] public bool UserVoted { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("userVotedUp")] public bool? UserVotedUp { get; set; }
    }

    [JsonObject]
    public class Root
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("posts")] public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("next")] public string Next { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is my ViewModel - PostsViewModel.cs in ViewModels folder:

```
using App.Models;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace App.ViewModels;

public class PostsViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private string _type;
    public string Type { get =>  _type; set { _type = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Type)); } }
    private string _username;
    public string Username { get => _username; set { _username = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Username)); } }
    private string _communityName;
    public string CommunityName { get => _communityName; set { _communityName = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CommunityName)); } }
    private string _title;
    public string Title { get => _title; set { _title = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Title)); } }
    private string _body;
    public string Body { get => _body; set { _body = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Body)); } }

    public ICommand LoadPostsCommand { get; set; }

    public PostsViewModel() 
    {
        LoadPostsCommand = new Command(async () => await LoadPosts());
    }
    private async Task LoadPosts()
    {
        var url = $"https://discuit.net/api/posts";
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
        var successCode = await client.GetAsync(url);

        // validate connection
        if (successCode.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("Code 200 -  Successful Connection to REST API");
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");

            var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
            {
                PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true,
            };
            var posts = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Posts>(data, options);
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("Data: " + data);
            Console.WriteLine("Posts: " + posts);
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");

            var Type = posts.Type;
            var Username = posts.Username;
            var CommunityName = posts.CommunityName;
            var Title = posts.Title;
            var Body = posts.Body;    
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error connecting to API");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Content Page code behind - HomePage.xaml.cs in Views folder:

```
using App.ViewModels;

namespace App.Views;
public partial class HomePage : ContentPage
{
    public HomePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new PostsViewModel();
    }
}
```

Here is my Content Page - HomePage.xaml in Views folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App.Views.HomePage" Title="Posts"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:App.ViewModels"
             x:DataType="vm:PostsViewModel"
             >

    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding LoadPostsCommand}">
        <ListView.Header>
            <VerticalStackLayout
            Spacing="25"
            Padding="30,0"
            VerticalOptions="Center">

                <Button 
                    x:Name="UpdateBtn"
                    Text="Load Posts"
                    Command="{Binding LoadPostsCommand}"
                    Margin="10"
                    />

            </VerticalStackLayout>
        </ListView.Header>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextCell Text="{Binding Title}" Detail="{Binding Body}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ContentPage>
```

and here is the BaseViewModel.cs page that HomePage inherits:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace Disc.ViewModels;

public abstract class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected bool SetProperty<TValue>(ref TValue backingField, TValue value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (Comparer<TValue>.Default.Compare(backingField, value) == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }

        backingField = value;

        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);

        return true;
    }
}
```

and finally, here is my debug output:

```
[DOTNET] -----------------------------------
[DOTNET] Code 200 -  Successful Connection to REST API
[DOTNET] -----------------------------------
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Newtonsoft.Json.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.app/files/.__override__/Newtonsoft.Json.dll [External]
[DOTNET] -----------------------------------
[DOTNET] Data: {"posts":[{"id":"1775d55eb7515d9d1e2d7481","type":"text","publicId":"pTJMsSk9","userId":"176caa4ff743f7b0a2fa3ec2","username":"pH_low","userGroup":"mods","userDeleted":false,"isPinned":false,"communityId":"1770a5ebb222dcb14b21f6cd","communityName":"DiscoApp","communityProPic":null,"communityBannerImage":null,"title":"Update - July 17th","body":"Hello everyone!
[DOTNET] Posts: App.Models.Posts
[DOTNET] -----------------------------------
```

Thanks so much for taking a look!!

Comment: The API is returning an array of posts, but your model/VM is only setup to handle a single post.  And your ItemsSource is bound to a command, which is completely wrong

Comment: I also don't think your model is correct.  Use json2csharp.com to create a C# model of the json data

Comment: it should work either way.  Do whatever suits you

Comment: updated the model code, I wasn't sure if on the List ones like public List<Post> if I should do the [JsonPropertyName("posts")] public List<Post> Posts { get; set; } thing with JsonPropertyName or not, or if I even need to do that at all since I'm using this in the viewmodel?:
`var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
                {
                    PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true,
                };`
Also, would you be able to expand on how I would change it to accommodate an array of posts instead of a single post -> or point me at a resource? @Jason

Comment: You want to deserialize into an object of type Root.  Then your ItemsSource will be the Posts property of that object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a property in your `VM` of type `Root`

```
[ObservableProperty]
Root data { get; set; }
```

deserialize your data into that property

```
Data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Root>(data, options);
```

then use `Data.Posts` as your `ItemsSource`

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Data.Posts}">
```

Comment: Dude, thank you so much!  It wouldn't take [ObservableProperty] (The type or namespace ObservableProperty could not be found) but looking at what that does, it seems like it just automates what I had done manually with the other variables, so I replicated that with Data instead. Does ObservableProperty not exist in Maui? I tried adding using System.Collections.ObjectModel; but it was greyed out like it was already included.   Anyway, it is working now and I understand this a lot better now - thank you again for helping me out!! I'd upvote your answer but I'm sub 15 rep since I'm so new.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/generators/observableproperty

Comment: Ah, I see.  I wasn't using the mvvm communitytoolkit - thanks again!  Got that installed and now it is working like a charm :)

Now I just need to figure out how to change this so it loads when the page does instead of on a button press.  Back to the books!

Comment: Use OnAppearing

Comment: Thanks, that's where I ended up - but for some reason it still only works when I press the button and not when the page loads, despite the OnAppearing() and button press calling the same function (though the button does so through the LoadPostsCommand command instead of straight to the LoadPosts like OnAppearing() does.  I must have something not quite right, going to futz with it for a while.